# Angular 6 children routes with lazy loading

Tags: routes, lazy-loading, angular6

I must access the skills route and it is not possible for me in any.
I have tried in many ways and I can not access the skills route following the structure of the code. my idea is to be able to access the children path of dashboard module

Thank you very much in advance.

```
// app.routing.module.ts

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

// components for route controller 
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { 
        path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' 
    },
    {
        path: 'home', component: HomeComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'dashboard',
        loadChildren: '../app/modules/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
    }

];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

....

```
// dashboard.routing.module.ts

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

// AuthGuardService

import { AuthGuard } from '../../shared/guards/auth-guard.service';

// routing components
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';
import { DashboardHomeComponent } from './components/dashboard-home/dashboard-home.component';
import { SkillsComponent } from './components/skills/skills.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: DashboardHomeComponent,
        outlet: "dashboard"
      },
      {
        path: 'skills',
        component: SkillsComponent,
        outlet: "dashboard"
      }
    ]
  }

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DashboardRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the DashboardModule imports DashboardRoutingModule

```js
// dashboard.module.ts

...
import DashboardRoutingModule  from './dashboard.routing.module.ts'.

@NgModule({
  imports: [DashboardRoutingModule]
});
```